# Spacing between counters and text in easylist

Tags: pdftex, easylist

I have a list with some positives and negatives, so I'm using plus and minus sign instead of the bullets in the itemize style, but there isn't any spacing between them and the text. Which I solved by adding a `space` after the plus and minus symbol `\ListProperties(Hide=2, Progressive=0cm, Style*1=$+$ , Style*2=$-$ ,)` but it just feels wrong. Is there any other way or is this how you really do it?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it just hit me that you can add `\hspace{.3em}` after the `Style*1=$+$`. So like this `\ListProperties(Hide=2, Progressive=0cm, Style*1=$+$\hspace{.3em}, Style*2=$-$\hspace{.3em},)` and it will be 100% same as the default spacing of easylist